# How to combine 2 Jquery Plugin Codes?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, google-web-designer

I have 2 Jquery plugins I want to combine them into one without losing any one's functionality. I tried but the code stops working I think I might be doing wrong. Please Help me.

**Plugin Code 1:**

```
!(function ($) {
    jQuery.fn.menuify = function (settings) {
        var config = { seperator: "_", class: "blogger-menu" };

        if (settings) jQuery.extend(config, settings);

        this.each(function () {
            // element-specific code here
            let ul = document.createElement("ul");
            let parentLi = [];
            let findChild = $(this).find("li a");
            let regex = RegExp(config.seperator, "g");
            ul.className = config.class;
            $(findChild).each(function () {
                let link = $(this).attr("href");
                let level = ($(this).text().match(regex) || []).length;
                if (level === 0) {
                    let li = document.createElement("li");
                    let a = document.createElement("a");
                    a.innerHTML = $(this).text();
                    a.href = link;
                    li.append(a);
                    parentLi[level + 1] = li;
                    ul.append(li);
                } else if (level > 0) {
                    let ul = document.createElement("ul");
                    let li = document.createElement("li");
                    let a = document.createElement("a");
                    a.innerHTML = $(this).text().replaceAll(config.seperator, "");
                    a.href = link;
                    li.append(a);
                    parentLi[level + 1] = li;
                    ul.append(li);
                    parentLi[level].append(ul);
                }
            });
            $(this).parent().html(ul);
        });

        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

The above code converts single-level list to multi-level unordered list.

**Plugin Code 2:**
Second code is [manumaker.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cssmenumaker/jQuery-Plugin-Responsive-Drop-Down/master/js/menumaker.js)
The above code converts the multilevel list to responsive menu bar it has some CSS code. This code can be seen [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cssmenumaker/jQuery-Plugin-Responsive-Drop-Down/master/js/menumaker.js)

The Codes basically used to make navigation menus.

Comment: Can I ask why are you trying to do such thing?

Comment: Actually i am making nav menu in blogger blog and using list widget for that in which i use _ as a short code to make it a child list.

Comment: no, I mean why are you trying to combine both plugins instead of calling them separately?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem comes from the fact that you have on one plugin the variable $ and on the other jQuery assigned to jQuery, with both of them assigned to $ it should work :

```
        (function($) {

        $.fn.menuify = function (settings) {
            var config = { seperator: "_", class: "blogger-menu" };

            if (settings) $.extend(config, settings);

            this.each(function () {
                // element-specific code here
                let ul = document.createElement("ul");
                let parentLi = [];
                let findChild = $(this).find("li a");
                let regex = RegExp(config.seperator, "g");
                ul.className = config.class;
                $(findChild).each(function () {
                    let link = $(this).attr("href");
                    let level = ($(this).text().match(regex) || []).length;
                    if (level === 0) {
                        let li = document.createElement("li");
                        let a = document.createElement("a");
                        a.innerHTML = $(this).text();
                        a.href = link;
                        li.append(a);
                        parentLi[level + 1] = li;
                        ul.append(li);
                    } else if (level > 0) {
                        let ul = document.createElement("ul");
                        let li = document.createElement("li");
                        let a = document.createElement("a");
                        a.innerHTML = $(this).text().replaceAll(config.seperator, "");
                        a.href = link;
                        li.append(a);
                        parentLi[level + 1] = li;
                        ul.append(li);
                        parentLi[level].append(ul);
                    }
                });
                $(this).parent().html(ul);
            });

            return this;
        };

      $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {
          
          var cssmenu = $(this), settings = $.extend({
            title: "Menu",
            format: "dropdown",
            breakpoint: 768,
            sticky: false,
            menuify: true
          }, options);

          return this.each(function() {
            cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');
            if (settings.format != 'select') {
              cssmenu.prepend('<div id="menu-button">' + settings.title + '</div>');
              $(this).find("#menu-button").on('click', function(){
                $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
                var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
                if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) { 
                  mainmenu.hide().removeClass('open');
                }
                else {
                  mainmenu.show().addClass('open');
                  if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
                    mainmenu.find('ul').show();
                  }
                }
              });

              multiTg = function() {
                cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
                cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
                  $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
                  if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
                    $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
                  }
                  else {
                    $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').show();
                  }
                });
              };

              if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
              else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');
            }

            else if (settings.format === 'select')
            {
              cssmenu.append('<select style="width: 100%"/>').addClass('select-list');
              var selectList = cssmenu.find('select');
              selectList.append('<option>' + settings.title + '</option>', {
                                                             "selected": "selected",
                                                             "value": ""});
              cssmenu.find('a').each(function() {
                var element = $(this), indentation = "";
                for (i = 1; i < element.parents('ul').length; i++)
                {
                  indentation += '-';
                }
                selectList.append('<option value="' + $(this).attr('href') + '">' + indentation + element.text() + '</option');
              });
              selectList.on('change', function() {
                window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
              });
            }

            if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');

            resizeFix = function() {
              if ($(window).width() > settings.breakpoint) {
                cssmenu.find('ul').show();
                cssmenu.removeClass('small-screen');
                if (settings.format === 'select') {
                  cssmenu.find('select').hide();
                }
                else {
                  cssmenu.find("#menu-button").removeClass("menu-opened");
                }
              }

              if ($(window).width() <= settings.breakpoint && !cssmenu.hasClass("small-screen")) {
                cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
                cssmenu.addClass('small-screen');
                if (settings.format === 'select') {
                  cssmenu.find('select').show();
                }
              }
            };
            resizeFix();
            if (settings.menuify === true) $(cssmenu).menuify();
            return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);

          });
      };
    })(jQuery);
```

**EDIT:** I've changed a little bit the code in order to chain the two plugins. Now when calling $.fn.menumaker, you have an option to call menuify or not.

```
$("#cssmenu").menumaker({
            title: "Menu - Mobile",              // The text of the button which toggles the menu
            breakpoint: 768,            // The breakpoint for switching to the mobile view
            format: "multitoggle",       // It takes three values: dropdown for a simple toggle menu, select for select list menu, multitoggle for a menu where each submenu can be toggled separately
            menuify: true //True by default
        });
```

Please note that I'm not sure why you're trying to achieve with menuify and that it's possible the 2 plugins counters themselves.

A simpler way to chain those 2 plugins without changing the code could also be like this :

```
$('#cssmenu').menumaker().menuify();
```

Comment: Actually i want to add extra functionality in the second plugin code and that extra functionality code is the first one.

Comment: So what you want is for example to do $(var).menumaker(options) and that is calls $.fn.menuify afterwards ?

Comment: @M.Muzammil the edit my answer your question